# selenium firefox profile exception

Tags: selenium, webdriver

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.  (Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:64)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:50)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:111)
                at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:78)
                at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:93)
                at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:142)
                at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:88)
                at com.ensarm.crawler.web.browser.FirefoxBrowser.initialize(FirefoxBrowser.java:296)
                at com.ensarm.crawler.navigator.IpProxyNavigator.initialize(IpProxyNavigator.java:46)
                at com.ensarm.crawler.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:23)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

```
  this is my ivy.xml file .
   <dependencies>
    <dependency org="antlr" name="antlr" rev="2.7.6"/>
    <dependency org="aopalliance" name="aopalliance" rev="1.0"/>
     <dependency org="bouncycastle" name="bcmail-jdk14" rev="139"/>
     <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.1"/>
     <dependency org="commons-dbcp" name="commons-dbcp" rev="1.4"/>
     <dependency org="commons-httpclient" name="commons-httpclient" rev="3.1"/>
               <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1"/>
               <dependency org="commons-pool" name="commons-pool" rev="1.6"/>
               <dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1"/>
               <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="ejb3-persistence" rev="1.0.2.GA"/>
               <dependency org="org.apache.pdfbox" name="fontbox" rev="1.6.0"/>
               <dependency org="jtidy" name="jtidy" rev="4aug2000r7-dev"/>
               <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.20.0"/>
                <dependency org="javax.inject" name="javax.inject" rev="1"/>
               <dependency org="javax.transaction" name="jta" rev="1.1"/>
               <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.0.2.GA"/>
               <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-cglib-repack" rev="2.1_3"/>
               <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-annotations" rev="3.5.6-Final"/>
               <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.0"/>
               <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-jcl" rev="1.6.0"/>
               <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.0"/>
               <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-simple" rev="1.6.0"/>  
               <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.18"/>
               <dependency org="pdfbox" name="pdfbox" rev="0.7.3"/>
               <dependency org="jaxen" name="jaxen" rev="1.1.1"/>
               <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.webdriver" name="webdriver-firefox" rev="0.9.7376"/>
               <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.webdriver" name="webdriver-common" rev="0.9.7376"/>
               <dependency org="javassist" name="javassist" rev="3.4.GA"/>
               <dependency org="net.sf.hibernate4gwt" name="hibernate4gwt" rev="1.0.4"/>
               <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-server" rev="2.20.0"/>
                </dependencies>

  getting above exception.. dont know which jar is missing...
```

Comment: are you sure you have all the libraries required by selenium in your build path?

Comment: yes.. I am using Ivy for dependency management... I added selenium-java 2.20.0 ,webdriver-common-0.9.7376.jar
webdriver-firefox-0.9.7376.jar in my Ivy.xml file.

Comment: are you adding any other dependencies other than the ones mentioned above or just the 3?

Comment: yes i am adding hibernate dependecies ....

Comment: I'd like to have ivy download the standalone server from repo1 along with 
all of the other selenium dependencies, but I don't see it anywhere in the 
selenium tree: 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi these are all the jars maven downloaded for me when I used selenium

- selenium-java-2.20.0.jar
- selenium-android-driver-2.20.0.jar
- selenium-remote-driver-2.20.0.jar
- cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
- json-20080701.jar
- guava-11.0.1.jar jsr305-1.3.9.jar
- selenium-chrome-driver-2.20.0.jar
- selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.20.0.jar
- selenium-api-2.20.0.jar
- htmlunit-2.9.jar xalan-2.7.1.jar
- serializer-2.7.1.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar
- httpmime-4.1.2.jar
- commons-codec-1.4.jar
- htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar
- xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
- nekohtml-1.9.15.jar
- cssparser-0.9.5.jar
- sac-1.3.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- httpclient-4.1.2.jar
- httpcore-4.1.2.jar
- selenium-firefox-driver-2.20.0.jar
- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- commons-exec-1.1.jar
- selenium-ie-driver-2.20.0.jar
- jna-3.4.0.jar
- platform-3.4.0.jar
- selenium-iphone-driver-2.20.0.jar
- selenium-support-2.20.0.jar

I suggest you get them all then start removing one by one until you find what it actually needs.

Comment: when i add same ivy library to project on the other machine then it works fine ..  :( but not on my machine..

Comment: It might be you have a bad installation on your IDE.  I suggest you try with a clean IDE installation on your machine